# I Want Mobile And PC Both Not Allow Character Only Number Allow

Tags: jquery, html

I Have Code For Input And Search Button And Code OF Allow Only Number 
 Into Desktop It Not Allow But character But Into Mobile It Allow I want Both Are Not Allow character

Track

```
<script>

    function isNumber(evt) {
        var iKeyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
        if (iKeyCode != 46 && iKeyCode > 31 && (iKeyCode < 48 || iKeyCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;
    }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer This snippet, It will work on both PC n mobile.

```js
$( "input" ).on( "keypress", function(evt) {
        var iKeyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
        if (iKeyCode != 46 && iKeyCode > 31 && (iKeyCode < 48 || iKeyCode > 57)){
           return false;
        }
        return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```